# apache reverse proxy configuration

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am trying to configure reverse proxy for one application.
Am using apache 2.2 web server 
below are my configuration rules

ProxyRequests     off

ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass /app/  (http://11.11.111.11:123/)

ProxyPassReverse /app/  http://11.11.111.11:123/

Problem:
When i hit the url of my local server like myserver.co.in/app/
first page is coming (application log in page). after that application is redirecting to url  myserver.co.in/home/index.html and redirection failed. since "/app/" part is missing in the url.

Can any one help me to fix this issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to fix the path getting returned from your application. You'll have to prefix `/app` where necessary to the URLs it generates

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify your app to add the `/app` prefix or use `mod_proxy_html`.

The following is quoted from "[When ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse aren’t enough](http://brian.olore.net/wp/2013/07/when-proxypass-and-proxypassreverse-arent-enough/)" and is modified to suite what you've asked.

In a nutshell, [`mod_proxy_html`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) allows you to rewrite html, javascript & css so that the URLs can cleanly go through your reverse proxy. This means that the backend application responds with

```
<script src="/script/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

mod_proxy_html will converted it to

```
<script src="/app/script/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To get this to work, add the following to httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /app/ (http://11.11.111.11:123/)
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://11.11.111.11:123/
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://11.11.111.11:123/ /app/

<Location /app/>
  ProxyHTMLEnable On
  ProxyPassReverse http://11.11.111.11:123/
  SetOutputFilter proxy-html
  ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app/
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /app /app
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

because apache dosnt know you want a different page, you need to set working directory for this virtual host to the directory where you app is.

For example,

```
DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
```

so using your config would be

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /app/ (http://11.11.111.11:123/)
    ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://11.11.111.11:123/
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```